# Does mongo TTL refresh when document is changed?

Tags: mongodb, ttl

Say I have a TTL of 15 minutes on a MongoDB Index. If I have a document such as `{"name": "James"}` and update it to `{"name": "Other name"}` after 10 minutes, will the document then delete itself after 5 minutes (i.e. the TTL wasn't updated), or after 15 minutes (i.e. the TTL was refreshed)?

Comment: If you haven't changed the value of the TTL field, then it uses the first behavior (deletes after the remaining 5m).

Comment: @user20042973 if the index is against the `name` field in this case, would the index refresh then (since the value of the field which the TTL is against has changed)?

Comment: You can't have a TTL index against the name field. [Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data): "_If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that holds one or more date values, the document will not expire._"